# How to display Excel file in an asp page choosing range

Tags: html, asp.net, excel

I am really new to asp.net I have found many hints about how to download and open in excel an excel page but what I'd like is to show the excel file in the asp page choosing the range to be shown. Is that possible?
something like this:
[image]

By doing so I'd make this file available to be seen to everyone even people not having excel.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [this](http://www.groupdocs.com/dot-net/document-viewer-library) library

or convert the Excel file to a pdf and easily [display](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/5089e0/how-to-open-pdf-files-in-web-brower-using-asp-net/) it